# Disable VAT for specific countries in WooCommerce for all delivery methods except for local pickup

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Greeting,

this code works great.
If someone is able to adapt the code to work so if **someone chooses local pickup to return the tax**

```
function extempt_vat_for_non_eu_firms( $post_data ) {

  WC()->customer->set_is_vat_exempt( false );

  parse_str( $post_data, $output );

  $countries_without_vat = array('BA','RS','ME','MK');

  if(in_array($output['billing_country'], $countries_without_vat)) {
    WC()->customer->set_is_vat_exempt( true );
  }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'extempt_vat_for_non_eu_firms' );
```

I tried to correct the code but I couldn't find a solution